# Android/Eclipse: Configuring a custom AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In the AVD manager for Android in Eclipse I can specify the size of the SD card storage, the "skin", the screen resolution, and certain hardware specs.

But what if I wanted to make something that specifically resembled a particular phone, say the Droid Incredible?   Then I'd also need to have a row of little buttons below the screen for Home, Menu, Back and Search.    Is there a step-by-step document describing how to configure/customize an AVD to that level of detail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy a skin such as $SDK/platforms/android-4/skins/QVGA into your own custom skin $SDK/platforms/android-4/skins/YOURCUSTOMSKIN. Examining that folder (especially the "layout" file) should be enough to get you started with modifications. The AVD manager should pick up the skin and offer it as an alternative.